# Package does not exist (Maven)

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea

i'm facing a strange problem, I've already searched about it and none of the solutions worked. I was working on my personal project, then suddenly [Maven starts complaining about the package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5OmLL.png), but IntelliJ seems to be [working when importing the classes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqBaJ.png). I have two modules (web and persistence), and web depends on persistence. Here's the source code, https://github.com/VictorHenrique317/MaxPapers . I appreciate any help

Comment: Your projects work fine without error "Package does not exist". Try to invalidate cache and restart IntelliJ IDEA

Comment: @AlekseyKurkov Didn't work, I guess the problem has something to do with Intellij?

Comment: Did you try deleting the source code from your machine, re-cloning the repository and re-importing it into your IDE? A fresh start. You can also try deleting the contents of your `.m2/repository` if the package in question is in a jar from a maven dependency. When you rebuild, it will download all dependencies fresh and flush out any corrupted files.

Comment: @OTheriault I tried re-cloning after Aleksey said the project was working on his machine, and still didn't work

Comment: Somehow when I executed the clean -> build lifecycles (instead of the clean install goal) on the root module the error disappeared. But interestingly, if I execute clean -> install the problem returns. Why is it?

Comment: You need to first clean and install the `persistence` module and only then `web` module (which depends on `persistence`). This is similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19650743/clean-install-multiple-maven-projects-in-order-without-reactor